# Crawling unreferenced URLS

Tags: php, html, asp.net, web-crawler

I have been building a tool from scratch to generate a visual graph of webpages in a particular domain name. If a page links to another page it is denoted by an edge in the graph. My project is to investigate how web developers link their pages inside a particular website. My aim is to run this tool on around 100 non profit websites and analyse the results.

There's a catch :

Some pages are not linked by any other page on the internet(They are standalone pages). Is there any way I can get a list of such  webpages in a particular domain name or a particular directory in a domain name.

Example : Say we have www.example.com/abc/xyz.asp
xyz.asp is not linked by any other page on internet and also directory listing at the parent directory (www.example.com/abc/ ) is disabled. How do I get to know that a webpage exists in that particular location.

I m particularly interested in asp and php domains. My assumption is that linked pages will form a cluster and standalone pages will be left alone like stars in the sky. After generating the graph I need to calculate some co-efficients.

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

Comment: If you are talking to orphaned deep links, then AFAIK there is no way to get them. If directory browsing is disabled for `domain.com/foo` and no trace (link, robots.txt, etc) leads to a deep link like `domain.com/foo/boo.html` you can only obtain a valid url by brute forcing (which I do not suggest). This is intended behaviour. If you are talking about websites, like "my_page_is_not_in_google.com" then you will need to get domain registrar lists for those sites.